# How is the $ of awk different from $ of shell?

Tags: shell, awk

In awk, we use `$` to extract the contents of the matched lines (based on pattern) separated by the `IFS`

```
awk `/LIG/{print $1, $2}' topol.top
```

In shell, we use `$` for extracting the value which we stored for a variable. for eg. `for` loop.

```
for i in *; do
    mv -- $i $i.pdb; done
```

(Corrected based on an answer)

Is `$` usage in both these contexts essentially the same or different?

If different why is the difference? How to use awk and shell together with `$` intermingled?

Comment: See [Using Shell Variables in Programs](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Shell-Variables) in the GNU awk guide.

Comment: One of the commonest faults for awk novices is to assume awk has access to shell variables. They are distinct languages, each with their own scope. Even if you cram a shell expression into awk code with explicit quoting, any error in the shell part risks causing an awk syntax error during parsing, which will usually be impossible to diagnose or recreate.

Comment: but the role of the $ is in both cases to dereference a variable name, so essentially the same, to give a direct answer.

Comment: @ruud Yes. thats what i wished to confirm. though in many text it is written different -- both follow the same principle of dereferencing as rightly pointed out by you....

Comment: `IFS` has nothing to do with awk. awk has a variable named `FS` which has a similar purpose to `IFS` in shell.

Comment: @ruud no,  it's not. To dereference a variable name in awk is just `var` while in shell it's `$var`.

Comment: @ruud, no, that's a direct but **wrong** answer. awk's `$` references a field (one of those split from the input).

Comment: Be careful, your shell exemple should be : `for i in ./*; do mv "$i" "${i}.pdb" ; done` to be able to **handle spaces in filenames, and other things** (files beginning with a "-", for exemple). In a nutshell: always quote variables, unless very specific cases (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls , explaining why, and giving lots of other shell pitfalls)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$` in shell and `$` in awk only look like they're related because sometimes there can be a number and sometimes a variable after `$` in shell and the same is true in awk but they aren't in any way related, just the same character used by 2 completely different tools in 2 completely different contexts and what `$<number>` and `$<variable>` mean in shell is completely different from what they mean in awk.

In shell you dereference a variable by prepending it with `$` and the positional parameters, etc. are treated the same as variables in this regard so you can have:

```
$0 = the path to the current command
$1 = the first argument passed to the command
$2 = the second argument passed to the command
$# = the number of arguments passed to the command
$? = the exit status of the last command run
$var = the value of the shell variable var
etc.
```

In awk `$` is the name of the array (conceptually) of fields that the current record is split into so you **only** use `$` in these expressions:

```
$0 = the current record being processed
$1 = the first field of the current record
$2 = the second field of the current record
```

To dereference an awk variable `var`, you just use it's name `var`, just like in C, and in fact the awk syntax is far more similar to C than it is to shell.

If you ever see `$var` used in awk then it's not the `$` that's dereferencing `var`, it's the use of the name `var` alone that's dereferencing `var` and if `var` has a numeric value like say, `5`, then `$var` means the same as `$5` which is the 5th field of the current record whie if `var` does not have a numeric value then `$var` means the same as `$0` which is the current record:

```
var=0 => $var = $0 = the current record being processed
var=1 => $var = $1 = the first field of the current record
var=2 => $var = $2 = the second field of the current record
var="" => $var = $0 = the current record being processed
var="foo" => $var = $0 = the current record being processed
```

awk and shell are 2 completely different tools with their own syntax, semantics, and scope for variables etc. so just treat them as such and don't assume anything you see in an awk script is in any way related to anything you see in a shell script in syntax, semantics, or scope and vice-versa.

Comment: I find it useful to clarify that `$` in `awk` is more an operator like unary `-` or `!`. `- <expression>` converts `<expression>` to a number and gives you the opposite number, `$ <expression>` converts `<expression>` to an integer and gives the corresponding field (or the full record if that value is 0). `$ (1 + 1)` gives you the second field. `$ (1 - 1)` the full record. There are some variations between implementations when the `<expression>` is not an integer in the first place like with `$ "2"` (use `$ (0 + "2")` for portability or `$ 1.2` (use `$ int(1.2)` for portability).

Comment: In the case of `print $ "2"`, it looks more like a bug in gawk's parsing of the `print` statement.  `print($ "2")` or `a = $ "2"` seem fine but `print $ "2"` acts like `print $0`. `$ 1.2` is a problem with `mawk` only in my tests, and only for literal values, `a = 1.2; print $ a` is fine.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas At first I thought that was explicable by field reference being higher priority than all other operations except grouping but since `print $("2")`, `print ($"2")`, `printf "%s\n", $"2"`, and `a=$"2"; print a` all output the value of `$2`, I've abandoned that theory and agree, that looks like a bug. I shot the gawk guys an email to either have it filed as a bug report or get an explanation. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2020-06/msg00022.html

Comment: Great that a potential bug in `gawk` has been found @EdMorton

Comment: Seems the gawk folks agreed: ["It was a bug in the code that optimizes 'print $0' into the special op for plain 'print' which is more efficient."](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2020-06/msg00026.html)

Answer (score 0):

`$` is just a syntactical element which is similarily (but not identically) used in `awk` and in the shell:

- `$0`, `$1` etc in `awk` contain the whole line (`$0`) or the corresponding part of the line as separated by `FS`. All other variable names in `awk` are taken as-is and don't need a `$` so here the variable name actually *is*  `$0` etc
- `$anything` in `bash` etc is used to get the value of the variable called `anything`. And then there is `$(...)` which is used for command substitution so you *could* say that `$` means "the value of" in general in shells.

Comment: Can you give an example of command substitution `$(...)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar-M `now=$( date )`

Comment: @PraveenKumar-M From your question: `for i in $(ls); do`

Comment: ... which should really be `for i in *; do`.

Comment: @Kusalananda absolutely :-)

Comment: I kept it `*`  at the initial. Changed it. Will revert back.

Comment: They're not even used similarly. awk's `$` is an operator that references one of the numbered fields that result from splitting the input. In the shell, it's part of the syntax for variable/parameter expansions and some other expansions. In awk you can do something like `print $$1` (that's the `$` operator used twice) which has no remotely similar meaning in the shell (it's the `$$` special parameter, so it has a meaning, but it's not like it would be the same `$` twice), and of course `$var` means something completely different in both.

Comment: @Kusalananda .... which should be `for i in ./* ; do` to handle more easily pesky files starting with `-` ;)

Comment: @OlivierDulac For a variable value of "should be". You could also use `--` in front of the filename to signal that there are no more options on the command line.  It also depends on _how_ the names are used and the semantics of the utility one uses them with.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree with most of your remarks, but many older programs (and probably some current ones too, usually non-gnu) will not handle `--` as meaning "end of options"

Comment: @OlivierDulac Standard utilities, no matter whether they are GNU or not, handle `--` the same way. Non-standard utilities may need `./` depending on their semantics. Can you give an example of such a utility? Also, can you relate the current discussion to the question at hand?

Comment: @Kusalananda: a commonly used command, bash' echo will output the `--` instead of using it as a stop option. There are others common current ones (for exemple: test ) , as well as lots of non-gnu utilities present on older unixes. I learnt about using `./*` from the Unix faq on Usenet (where they had to warn about many differences between legacy systems, some of which survive to this day in some institutions).  I agree it is not directly related to the question itself, but it is, imo, important to relay this caveat of `*` vs `./*` when globbing files. I will delete all my comments if you want

Comment: @OlivierDulac `echo` should not be used to output variable data, and `test` should always be used with one of its test operators.